# Designing an algorithm to determine if a linear combination of k-1 sets is contained in the k-th set .

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am trying to solve the following problem - given $k$ sets : $A_1,A_2,...,A_k$ containing $O(n)$ integers each  I need to design an algorithm that will determine if there is such a group of elements $a_1\in A_1,$ $a_2\in A_2,\ldots,a_k\in A_k$ that will satisfy the equation: 
$a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{k-1}=a_k.$ The required runtime is $O\left(n^{\frac{k}{2}}\log n\right)$ for even $k$'s and $O\left(n^{\frac{k+1}{2}}\right)$ for odd $k$'s. I'd be grateful for some ideas.

Comment: I want to get some kind of a starting point or a direction to address this problem which I lack at the moment.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "containing $O(n)$ integers?"  Does this mean that the number of integers contained in $A_k is less than or equal to $k$?  $O(n)$ is a statement about functions, not numbers, so what you say doesn't make all that much sense.

Comment: As you said , it means that the number of elements in each set has an upper bound $n$ so to speak . This statement is a quote on quote from the homework page, not something I came up with. Either way, as long as the idea is clear now - this is at all not the main point of the task .

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas that may help you.  First, we can symmetrize the problem, by replacing each element of $A_k$ by its negative, then seek a solution to $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{k-1}+a_k=0$$
We can also go the other way, negating appropriate elements to get $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_j=a_{j+1}+a_{j+2}+\cdots+a_k$$

So, a general approach is this: calculate $A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_j$, that is all the sums of one element from each set.  Then, calculate $A_{j+1}+\cdots+A_k$.  Then see if there is any intersection between these sumsets.

You don't have to put the *first* sets on the left, though, you can divide $\{A_1,\ldots, A_k\}$ between the left side and the right side as you like (probably to make them as equal in size as possible).

Comment: I see, so in that case can I state that since there are n options for every element $a_i$ , where $i\in [1,j]$ , $i\in\mathbb{N}$ (as every set consists of at most n elements) then the worst-case runtime for picking up all of the combinations say for the left group is $O(n^j)$ $\iff \begin{cases}O(n^{\frac{k}{2}}) &, \text{k is even} \\ O(n^{\frac{k+1}{2}}) &, \text{k is odd} \end{cases}$ ?

Comment: That's right.  Then you need to include the time to check the intersection, which ought to be negligible in comparison.

Comment: I see Vadim . Thanks a lot for the help! .